# Google Cloud Datastore date field getting converted automatically

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore, google-cloud-bigtable, gql, gqlquery

I've got a table called Person with three columns:

- `id`
- `name`
- `registeredDate`

Where `registeredDate` is `LocalDateTime`.

I am trying to write a query using Query By GQl as following:

```
Select * from person
```

I'm getting the following data output

```
Id  name  registeredDate

1  Xyz   2009-10-09(09:30:00.000) IST
```

When I'm trying with following query:

```
Select Id, registeredDate from person
```

I'm getting following output:

```
Id  registeredDate

1. 1255060800000000
```

I don't know why the `datetime` field is not displaying properly. Why it is getting converted automatically. How to make it display as `LocalDateTime` format.

Answer (score 1):

[Date and time](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#date_and_time) value, returned as part of a [projection](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#projections) query, is being converted by the Datastore mode to microsecond integer values.

This is one of the [limitations on projections](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#limitations_on_projections) described in the documentation as follows:

> In the results of a projection query, Datastore mode converts
> timestamp values to microsecond integer values.

You'll need to use other query types to return the `registeredDate` not in microseconds.

Comment: I can go with other way writing a new query. But I need a way to convert it into LocalDateTime in java when it is fetching. Can anybody gives an example?

Comment: @SureshDVijay did you find a way to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue that my entity field is LocalDateTime and It returns Long with projection query